# Excel not providing correct calculation value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Excel work sheet has 10,000 lines of identical formulas on every row.

Column AH [formula: `AH=(M-AD)AB`]

In this case row 7502

M7502= `288` (value)
AB7502 = `0` [formula: `=IF(AND(MONTH(C7426)=MONTH($Y$1),YEAR(C7426)=YEAR($Y$1)),1,0)`]
AD7502 = `0` (value)

The result AH7502 is expected to equal `0` but shows the value of `288`

Notice:  If I click on the cell `AH7502` AND THEN CLICK ON THE FORMULA BAR it corrects the result to `0`.  Also if I enter `0` in cell `M7502` press enter it corrects the `AH7502` to `0`.

[image]

Comment: your calculations may be set on manual.

Comment: Calculation option is set to automatic.  Note: same formulas above and below are updating correctly.

Comment: How long does a recalc with F9 take?

Comment: Try to enter the value in M7502, AD7502 and AB7502 manually and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the cause of your specific issue, but sometimes when I create lots (IE thousands) of formulas, excel seems to fill in a guess for the displayed value, and doesn't actually update the display until I interact with the cell in some way (usually pasting over with actual values).

Comment: Is this just a limitation of excel.  Can anything be done to prevent "a guess" - this is causing a big problem.  Tried Shift+F9 to refresh excel to calculate but it does not fix the error or "guess".

Comment: @PhilWu It's not a calculation issue, just a display one so far as I can tell. So all the calculation advice is useless (and makes googling the problem very difficult). I did just find this that I'm going to try. Maybe it'll work for you. https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/4812ah/screen_refresh_issue_technical_issue/d0gs04d?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3